# Minimal trees around special nodes

Tags: graph, graph-theory, shortest-path, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a connected weighted undirected graph. The graph contains two types of nodes. Hub nodes and non-hub nodes.
What I would need is to  grow a tree from each hub node to every non-hub node so that every non-hub node belongs to exactly one tree and the sum of link weights in every tree is minimal. Also each non-hub node should belong to the tree growing from its nearest hub (meaning hub with shortest path from node). Also I want to skip nodes that have the same shortest path from two or more hubs.

Here are some examples [Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKtGL.png) [Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soVa4.png)

[image]
[image]

Red nodes are the hub nodes, yellow nodes in [Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soVa4.png) are the skipped node having the same shortest distance from two or more hub nodes. White nodes are just regular nodes. And the blue edges is the desired solution.

I need to find total cost of this solution, that is 18 in example1 and 42 in example2.

What I tried was to run Dijkstra algorithm simultaneously from all hub nodes and just add the weight of cheapest edge not connecting different trees to the total sum and marking the nodes to skip along the way. But it did not work for all graphs. Here is an example of failing case with this approach [Failing case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6dMA.png). While I would want this [Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKXkV.png).

Is there any algorithm to solve this kind of a problem? I will be glad for any advice. Thank you

Comment: The first one meaning splitting the graph by disjoint minimum spanning trees all expanding from different hub node. Maybe the examples in images will make it more clear.
It did not work because I got different results than what I was expecting. I couldn't find exactly what was wrong, I just thought there is a hole somewhere in my solution and am trying to come up with different approach

Comment: As I wrote I'm looking for the total cost of such solution. For some graphs it was working well but for some I just got different total cost than what I was expecting.

Comment: They must be connected components and they must be trees and they must be minimal and they must span from evey hub to every node having them as a closest hub. Sorry for unclear description this is my first post here. To the "keeping saying the same thing over and over", I don't know what you wanna hear more. I was expecting 2053 and got 2066 ?

Answer (score 0):

> grow a tree from each hub node to ...

Write code that does exactly this.

Grow the tress from every hub, "simultaneously". At each step add a link from  an existing tree to an unnatached node,  always choosing the next link which is the cheapest.

- Create forest of trees with just two nodes, one of the hub nodes, which will form the root of the trees.  If a hub has more than one link, create a tree for each link.
- Loop over links from nodes in the trees to unattached nodes, finding cheapest
- Add node at second end of cheapest link to tree containing first end
- Continue until all nodes attached to a tree.

Comment: That is correct I want each node to be assigned to the closest hub and the total cost of components to be minimal.

Here is an example of failing case. This is something what I would get from Dijkstra https://i.imgur.com/ieIaGF7.png but what I would really want is this https://i.imgur.com/Z82MoJf.png . Where node number 0 is hub. The cost in the wrong case is 14 and in the correct case is only 12.

Comment: "what I would really want is ..."  You have one hub.  The blue lines suggest you want to split the graph into two components.  On what basis do you do the spitting? "nearest hub" does not work, because there is only one.  You must be using some other criteria which you have not mentioned.

Comment: Number of components = number of hubs, but I think that is clear from the question and provided examples. If the graph in this failing example would be a subgraph of bigger graph with multiple hubs and all the nodes in the subgraph would have node number 0 as their nearest hub. So it should not depend on number of hubs. I will edit in the failing case

Comment: Because I want the total cost of this component to be minimal, that is why I called it "multiple minimal spanning trees" because I don't know what else to call it. I was using Dijkstra but that does not give me the expected result because node 1 would be connected to node 2 as you wrote. Each node must be connected to its nearest hub but it does not have to be through the shortest path.

Comment: It is still connected to the nearest hub through sequence of edges, I never said it should be connected along the shortest path, just that the total cost should be minimal

Comment: That is just the example where my method with Dijkstra failed. See the first two examples in the question there are also nodes connected to their nearest hub but NOT along the shortest path to the hub (Example1 node n.1)

Comment: Why? It is true, that it is the nearest hub for every node because there is no other hub. EDIT: That is exactly what I mean! Sorry for confusion

Comment: I would just add to your description that each non-hub node should belong to the tree growing from its nearest hub

Comment: I edited my question using some of your more clear description